# Datastructures where Add, Get kth largest are O(log n) and O(1)

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, sorting, data-structures

Give a data structure that stores comparable objects and supports `add()` and `get(k)` operations [`get(k)` returns the kth smallest element in the data structure `(1 <= k <= n)`]. `get(k)` must be `O(1)` and `add()` must be `O(log n)` where n is the number of objects added to the data structure. Give another structure where `get(k)` is `O(log n)` and add is `O(1)`

Comment: First one's easy; binary search to insert into a sorted list, take A[k] in constant time.

Comment: Hello @wrick, welcome to Stack Overfow. We're perfectly happy to help people with their homework, but we expect people to show that they've tried to solve the problem themselves, first.

Comment: @bdares - How is get(k) O(1) in your solution? Linked lists don't have O(1) random access. And, if its a array lists, then you don't get constant time insertions as you have to shift.

Comment: @samold - I am way out of college, this was just asked in a phone interview.

Comment: @wrick arrays have an added constant-time amortized cost for inserts, which shouldn't add anything significant to the O(logn) insertion time.  As cnicutar's answer states, a heap would also work, if you assume that you can calculate 2^k in constant time, which technically you can't but it's pretty damn close.

Comment: @bdares - Arrays have constant-time amortized for inserts at the END of the array and not at arbitrary indices which is required for your solution.

Comment: I am not sure why people claim it is homework without actually knowing a solution themselves... +1. Very interesting question.

Comment: @wrick that's right... well, the heap still works :P

Comment: @bdares: Please enlighten us with the heap solution. Note that k is an input to get. If k were constant, then I can see the heap working...

Comment: @wrick: Frank feedback: You could do with better title selection and formatting. In fact that is probably the reason people why poeple think it is homework: It looks like you didn't put in much effort in writing the question down.

Comment: @bdares - What heap solution? Heaps don't have constant time access to nth elements (it only has constant-time find-mins and find-maxes)

Comment: blech.  btilly explains my mistake.  I was thinking that you could find the jth child on the hth level in constant time, but that wouldn't necessarily be the kth largest element.

Comment: @wrick: Given the difficulty of the question (and thus the interest it may generate), I expect you'd get much more votes if it were presented nicely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's **no way** to build a deterministic comparison-based data structure with amortized O(1)-time adds and worst-case O(log n)-time gets. The other configuration cannot be ruled out by an information-theoretic lower bound, but I seriously doubt that anyone knows how to do it.

For the experts: the adversary first adds n items, answering the algorithm's O(n) comparisons in such a way as to leave an antichain of size at least log<sup>2</sup> n. It then chooses k in such a way that computing get(k) forces the algorithm to do selection on the antichain, incurring a cost of Ω(log<sup>2</sup> n).

Why can the adversary force such a large antichain? Suppose that the algorithm always left no antichain of more than log<sup>2</sup> n elements. By Dilworth's theorem, the elements can be partitioned into at most log<sup>2</sup> n chains, which can be merged using O(n log log n) comparisons, giving a sorting algorithm that uses o(n log n) comparisons and thus a contradiction.

What could your interviewer have meant? It's conceivable to me that if both operations are amortized, then there's a solution. This is a non-canonical relaxation of the requirements, however.

Comment: +1 great answer (although the theory is beyond me).  I'm looking forward to seeing more such answers.

Comment: Seems like a good approach. But possible issue: You are haven't accounted for the comparisons required to create the chains which you then merge i.e. nloglogn is an underestimate, IMO. If your proof is correct it implies that impossibility of polylog(n) (i.e. O(log ^k n)) worst case get which seems quite surprising.

Comment: @Aryabhatta The chains are created by the O(n) comparisons made during the calls to add().

Comment: @Aryabhatta We can actually push the upper bound on add() to o(log n)-time and the lower bound on get() to n^Ω(1). I'm not sure why this should be surprising; the O(n)-time selection algorithms all focus their efforts on the element to be selected.

Comment: @slowpoke: My point was: the chains being sorted is an additional assumption you are making, which you make use of in your claim of an O(n log logn) compares merge of chains algorithm. For instance if there were log^2 n chains of n/log^2n elements each, to sort each of them you would need Omega (n log n) compares while you are (indirectly) claiming O(n) is enough. The last sentence was just a remark, and in no way a disproof. I still find it surprising: there is a lot of leeway between n log n and n log^k n.

Comment: @Aryabhatta It's a proof by contradiction. If the algorithm were somehow able always to avoid large antichains, then we could build on it to make a sorting algorithm that uses o(n log n) comparisons. Sorting the chains requires 0 additional comparisons because they're already chains.

Comment: @Aryabhatta They are chains in the partial order generated by the algorithm's first O(n) comparisons. Since any two elements in such a chain are comparable, we can answer every comparison needed to sort the chain by examining only the results of past comparisons.

Comment: @slowpoke: I deleted my previous comment. I wasn't able to express myself clearly (and we were using terms differently). _Existence_ of a partition of chains does not imply that the algorithm _knows_ about it and can make use of it. You haven't yet shown that the algorithm can compute the partition of chains which are merged. In fact, as I claimed before, If an algorithm has a set of log^2 n chains ready to be merged, then it already must have made Omega(n log n) compares.

Comment: @Aryabhatta Dilworth's theorem posits the existence of chains with respect to partial order of comparisons the algorithm has **already** performed. Since we're doing an information-theoretic lower bound, the algorithm has all the time in the world to use whatever dumbass algorithm it wants to recover the chains, because it already knows the entire partial order.

Comment: @slow: I now think you are right, and what I have been saying has actually been supporting your statements! Apologies for wasting your time.

Answer (score 4):

If I got this interview question I would respond by saying that I am unaware of any such data structures, and suspect that they don't exist.  However I suspect that the data structures that the interviewer is thinking of are "sorted array" and "skip list" respectively.

I would then explain that retrieving any element of an array by position is O(1).  Figuring out where to insert it is O(log(n)).  However the actual insertion is O(n) due to having to move the rest of the array.  However the O(n) piece comes with very good constants.

For the skip list, retrieving is O(log(n)).  Inserting involves half of the time only modifying one element, 1/4 of the time editing 2, 1/8 of the time editing 3 and so on, which is an average of 2 elements.  That's O(1).  However you cannot insert an element without figuring where to put it.  And that lookup is O(log(n)).  (To make the insert truly O(1) you either need to collect O(log(n)) data on the lookup that you make available to the insert, or you need to create the moral equivalent of a doubly linked skip list.)

Answer (score 0):

I defer to the answer of @btilly , but I'm going to try another way to describe a data structure that has constant addition and constant get(k). This will use a lot of memory though.

Any feedback appreciated, I'm only just making this up as I go along ...

Imagine we're talking about a set of 8-bit integers. Therefore, there are 256 integers that can be members of the set.

Now, imagine a balanced binary tree containing all 256 integers as leaves, and 255 other non-leaf nodes, giving us 9 levels altogether. The shape of this tree is fixed, but we will store a count at each node. The count on each leaf node will simply be a `1` or `0` depending on whether that integer is currently a member of our set. The count at each non-leaf node will be the total of the leaves below it.

This will give us O(1) addition (and removal). Each time an element is added (or removed), exactly 9 nodes (the root node, the relevant leaf node, and 7 nodes in between) will have to have their count incremented(decremented).

I think this will also give us constant time lookup. If you want to find the kth-smallest element, simply start at the root node and work you way down towards the relevant leaf, moving to the left or right as necessary.

Comment: That's actually `O(log(max-value))`.  For a fixed max value (255), it's constant time.